# How to make flex and svg work in safari and IE11

Tags: html, css, svg, flexbox

I have a simple ribbon banner I'm trying to make and I have it working in Chrome but not Safari or Internet Explorer 11.

[CodePen Example](https://codepen.io/rbrander/pen/KqNjRV)

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <span class="text" style="">Sale <br/>20% off</span>
  <span>
    <svg height="100%"
         viewBox="0 0 4 24">
      <path d="M0 0 L 4 0 L 0 12 L 4 24 L 0 24 Z" fill="#6e3ba1" />
    </svg>
  </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.text {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #6e3ba1;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 4rem;
  border-top-left-radius: 0.2rem; 
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0.2rem;
}

.container {
  flex-direction: row; 
  display:flex; 
  flex-wrap: no-wrap; 
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch
}
```

When I tried this in IE11, I was getting a large gap between the text and the SVG.

When I tried this in Safari, the SVG didn't appear because the width was assigned a value of 0 (instead of scaling based on height).

BONUS:

If possible, I'd also love to round the corners on the right side (SVG).

Comment: Add fixed height to the container. i have modified your style try this out and let me know thanks. ------------------   .container {
  flex-direction: row; 
  display:flex; 
  flex-wrap: no-wrap; 
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
  height:180px;
    
}
svg{
  margin-left:-1px;
}

Comment: And also use vendor prefixes for all flex properties i.e. -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap; display:-webkit-flex;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optionally you can do this without an SVG, by using the pseudo element and `transform: skew()`.. .. and it has rounded corner at the right side as well ... and work in IE11, and for sure in Safari, though can't check since I don't like *apple's* :)

```css
.text {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  background-color: #6e3ba1;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 4rem;
  border-top-left-radius: 0.2rem; 
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0.2rem;
}

.text::before, .text::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 52%;
  transform-origin: left top;
  background-color: inherit;
  border-top-right-radius: 0.2rem; 
  transform: skew(-18deg)
}
.text::after {
  top: auto;
  bottom: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0.2rem;
  transform-origin: right bottom;
  transform: skew(18deg)
}

.container {
  flex-direction: row; 
  display:flex; 
  flex-wrap: no-wrap; 
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span class="text" style="">Sale! <br/>20% Off</span>
</div>
```